# Oracle searching a case insensive CLOB

Tags: oracle, case-insensitive, clob

I have some code that searches a CLOB, which works fine. I'm attempting to wrap it in a function that I found online so the search can be CASE insensitive but I am running into some syntax errors and was hoping someone could help me out.

Below is my test CASE. I'm using livesql in can anyone wants to emulate my environment. Thanks in advance to all who answer.

```
create or replace type se_obj is object (s number, e number);
/
create or replace type se_tbl is table of se_obj;
/

create or replace function search_clob(p_lob clob, p_what varchar2)
  return se_tbl
  pipelined
as
  len int := length(p_what);
  s   int;
  pos int := 1;
begin
  if p_lob is not null then
    loop
      s := instr(p_lob, p_what, pos);
      exit when s = 0;
      pipe row (se_obj(s, s + len - 1));
      pos := s + len;
    end loop;
  end if;
  return;
end;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upper_clob(p_clob CLOB) RETURN CLOB
AS
    v_clob         CLOB;        -- TEMPORARY CLOB TO WRITE TO
    v_posn           NUMBER := 1;    -- CURRENT POSITION WITHIN CLOB
    v_holder    VARCHAR2(4000);    -- CHARACTER STRING HOLDER

BEGIN
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(v_clob,TRUE,dbms_lob.CALL);
    WHILE (v_posn < dbms_lob.getlength(p_clob)) LOOP
        v_holder := dbms_lob.substr(p_clob,4000,v_posn);
        v_posn := v_posn + 4000;
        v_holder := upper(v_holder);
        dbms_lob.write(v_clob, length(v_holder),v_posn,v_holder);
    END LOOP;       
    return v_clob;
end;
/

create table t ( x int primary key, y clob );

-- works fine

select t.x id, l.s start_pos, l.e end_pos, dbms_lob.getlength(y) clob_len
from   t outer apply search_clob(y, 'hello world') l where l.s > 0

-- getting a syntax error 

select t.x id, l.s start_pos, l.e end_pos, dbms_lob.getlength(y) clob_len
from   t outer apply search_clob(upper_lob
(y), 'HELLO WORLD') l where l.s > 0
```

Comment: you donn't need `upper_lob` function, just use usual `upper`: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPPER.html

Comment: And to be honest, you don't need `search_clob` too - you can use simple lateral/outer apply subquery

Comment: lol - wouldn't it have been easier if you had answered my questions on the **oracle-tech** site in the first place? What I told you there (I won't answer the same question more than once) is global - across all web forums; and now you lost a good number of forum veterans who do not visit stackoverflow. Good luck with your problem!

Comment: @mathguy I'm a bit lost on new version of oracle forums... could you give me a link please where he did ask the same question there?

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov - https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4488884/search-a-clob-for-a-pattern/p1

Answer (score 0):

It's really overkill to call pl/sql functions for such purposes when you can easily achieve it in SQL...

Simple SQL example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=13fa9071bd6ad34ebbf5fd6de4907a34

Test data:

```sql
create table t ( x int primary key, y clob );

insert into t
  select 
     level,
     to_clob('x')
       ||rpad(' ',4000,' ')||to_char(level,'0000')
       ||rpad(' ',4000,' ')||to_char(level,'0000')
       ||rpad(' ',4000,' ')||to_char(level,'0000')
       as y
  from dual
  connect by level<=30;
commit;
```

Simple query:

```sql
select
  x, 
  length(y) clob_len,
  s.*
from t
     outer apply(
        select 
           nullif(instr(lower(t.y), :subs, 1, level),0) start_pos
          ,nullif(instr(lower(t.y), :subs, 1, level),0) + length('1') as end_pos
        from dual
        connect by instr(lower(t.y), :subs, 1, level)>0
     ) s
```

Or using modern SQL Macro: (tested on Oracle 19.11)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_clob(input_clob clob, search_string varchar2) return varchar2 SQL_MACRO is
BEGIN
  RETURN q'{
   select 
           nullif(instr(lower(search_clob.input_clob), search_clob.search_string, 1, level),0) start_pos
          ,nullif(instr(lower(search_clob.input_clob), search_clob.search_string, 1, level),0)
            + length(search_clob.search_string) as end_pos
        from dual
        connect by instr(lower(search_clob.input_clob), search_clob.search_string, 1, level)>0
  }';
END;
/
select
  x, 
  length(y) clob_len,
  s.*
from t
     outer apply search_clob(t.y, '1') s
```

Example using the first query:

```sql
SQL> var subs varchar2(10);
SQL> exec :subs:='1';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select
  2    x,
  3    length(y) clob_len,
  4    s.*
  5  from t
  6       outer apply(
  7          select
  8           nullif(instr(lower(t.y), :subs, 1, level),0) start_pos
  9          ,nullif(instr(lower(t.y), :subs, 1, level),0) + length('1') as end_pos
 10          from dual
 11          connect by instr(lower(t.y), :subs, 1, level)>0
 12       ) s;

         X   CLOB_LEN  START_POS    END_POS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1      12016       4006       4007
         1      12016       8011       8012
         1      12016      12016      12017
         2      12016
         3      12016
         4      12016
         5      12016
         6      12016
         7      12016
         8      12016
         9      12016
        10      12016       4005       4006
        10      12016       8010       8011
        10      12016      12015      12016
        11      12016       4005       4006
        11      12016       4006       4007
        11      12016       8010       8011
        11      12016       8011       8012
        11      12016      12015      12016
        11      12016      12016      12017
        12      12016       4005       4006
        12      12016       8010       8011
        12      12016      12015      12016
        13      12016       4005       4006
        13      12016       8010       8011
        13      12016      12015      12016
        14      12016       4005       4006
        14      12016       8010       8011
        14      12016      12015      12016
        15      12016       4005       4006
        15      12016       8010       8011
        15      12016      12015      12016
        16      12016       4005       4006
        16      12016       8010       8011
        16      12016      12015      12016
        17      12016       4005       4006
        17      12016       8010       8011
        17      12016      12015      12016
        18      12016       4005       4006
        18      12016       8010       8011
        18      12016      12015      12016
        19      12016       4005       4006
        19      12016       8010       8011
        19      12016      12015      12016
        20      12016
        21      12016       4006       4007
        21      12016       8011       8012
        21      12016      12016      12017
        22      12016
        23      12016
        24      12016
        25      12016
        26      12016
        27      12016
        28      12016
        29      12016
        30      12016

57 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you both for your help and expertise. I just used upper in the CLOB column and the search pattern and it solved my problem